# PHP Recursive function issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble with the `getNext()` function...

If `isTaken() == true`, it does update `last`, but I'm not sure it is invoking the `getNext()` function as the function never returns `$next`.

If `isTaken() == false`, `$next` is returned.

Any ideas?

```
function isTaken ($id){
  $sql = "SELECT asset_no FROM tb_asset WHERE asset_no='" . $id . "'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_Error());
  if (mysql_num_rows($result)) return true;
  else return false;  
  mysql_free_result($result);
}


function getNext(){
  $sql = "SELECT last FROM app_asset";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  $last = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  mysql_free_result($result);

  $next = ++$last['last'];

  if (isTaken($next)){
    $sql = "UPDATE app_asset SET last='" . $next . "'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    getNext();
  } else {  
    return $next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_query`. It's deprecated and insecure.

Comment: @MattDiamant what do you suggest...mysqli?  Or are you refering to the way `mysql_query` is used?

Comment: @Mike PDO or MySQLi are the usual replacements. See [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/) or [this page in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sable Foste pointed out, you will always need a return statement. In your case however, it looks like your code needs to be modified to

```
if (isTaken($next)){
    //code
    return getNext();
} else
    return $next;
```

So the function will stop the recursion and return once `isTaken($next)` is false

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable back to the function:

```
  if (isTaken($next)){
    $sql = "UPDATE app_asset SET last='" . $next . "'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    getNext();
    return $next; // this line added.
  } else {  
    return $next;
  }
```

Comment: Actually this could be simplified to `if (..) {...} return $next;` (since both cases of the if have the same return statement), but you made your point clear.

Comment: That does not work.  I can only return `$next` when `isTaken()` == false.  In your answer `$next` is returned before the function is finished and returns a result that is taken.

Comment: @Mike, because this is a recursive array, you need to return something on every recursion.  Otherwise, you will only get the final result if no recursion occurs.  If not `$next`, then use a different value to return.